# Adding disk and converting RAID 0 to 5

Tags: filesystem, raid

I used MDADM to create a 4-disk RAID 0. I have another disk I want to add and convert the array to RAID 5. I'm already aware of the risks of RAID 5 but it is my best option at this time. How would I go about doing this? I formatted it with the ext4 system. I already have files on the partition.